# What projective tests are available for a child and family assessment?

Tags: measurement, personality, test

I’m thinking about introducing to my practice some new tests for family relationship evaluation. There are not so many projective tests in this matter. I'm particularly interested in Family Relation Test: Children’s Version (FRTC), however, I couldn’t found any information about a real experience of this test usage by specialists, only its general description on the website of a publisher. What are the strengths and the weaknesses of FRTC?

In general, what projective tests for a child and family assessment are there on the market today, except of classic drawing tests or TAT?

Answer (score 3):

Many projective tests explore family relationships, however it is frankly difficult to find projective tests exclusively focused on family relationships, can be proved:

- The Family Drawing Test (the most utilized).
- CAT (version of TAT for children) very, but very used.
- Test by Patte Noire of Louis Corman.
- FTT Riding theory test of Carina Coulacoglou.
- Test of Luisa Düss.
- TRO of Phillipson (officially focused on a person's ability to establish satisfying relationships with others, emotions in relationships)